# Finding the adjoint of an operator A

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, hilbert-spaces

1) Consider the operator $A:L_2[0,1]\longrightarrow L_2[0,1]$ defined by $Ax(t)=\int_0^1t x(s)ds$. What is the adjoint of A?

2) Consider the operator $A:L_2[0,1]\longrightarrow L_2[0,1]$ defined by $Ax(t)=\int_0^1t x(t)dt$. What is the adjoint of A?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Why did you ask the same question twice?  Also, what exactly have you tried so far?

Comment: So one is an integral ds, the other is an integral dt.  Still: the question doesn't quite make sense as written.  Also, what have you tried?

Comment: $f(x)$ appears nowhere in the right hand side of either of your expressions.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** Currently, 2) is the only question which kind of makes sense as phrased, but my best interpretation is that
$$
[Af](x) = \int_0^1 t f(t)\,dt
$$
With that,
$$
\langle Af,g \rangle = 
\int_0^1 \left(\int_0^1 t f(t)\,dt\right) \overline{g(s)}\,ds \\
= \int_0^1 \int_0^1 t \,f(t)\, \overline{g(s)}\,dt\,ds\\
= \int_0^1 \int_0^1 t \,f(t)\, \overline{g(s)}\,ds\,dt \\
= \int_0^1 f(t)\left(\overline{t\int_0^1 g(s)\,ds}\right)\,dt
= \langle f, ??? \rangle
$$